# Symfony 2 asgoodasnu/google-spreadsheet-bundle

Tags: php, symfony, google-sheets

I`m new to Symfony.
I need to use asgoodasnu/google-spreadsheet-bundle (called also WkGoogleSpreadsheetBundle) with Symfony 2 project. In usage section of bundle there is example like this:

"The service wk_google_spreadsheet provides direct interaction with the Google Spreadsheet PHP Client. You can invoke all methods of the client directly on the service".

So I wrote this code:

```
$service = $container->get('wk_google_spreadsheet');

$service->getSpreadsheets();
$service->getSpreadsheetById();
$service->getListFeed();
$service->getCellFeed();
```

But I don`t know how to this should be done, because first I need what means variable $container.

When I put in Controller something like this:

```
use Google_Client;
use Google\Spreadsheet\DefaultServiceRequest;
use Google\Spreadsheet\ServiceRequestFactory;
use Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService;
```

and then in action:

```
public function importAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $service = $container->get('wk_google_spreadsheet');
    $entity = new Settlement();
    $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity, $id);
 ...
}
```

I have error "Notice: Undefined variable: container."

So where and how I`d to define $container.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figured what should I do. The line with $service should be like:

```
$service = $this->container->get('wk_google_spreadsheet');
```

and **not** like this:

```
$service = $container->get('wk_google_spreadsheet');
```

But still I have a problem with lines:

```
$service->getSpreadsheets();
$service->getSpreadsheetById();
$service->getListFeed();
$service->getCellFeed();
```

On the first one I have an error like:
String could not be parsed as XML

Where the problem is? Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you are in a Symfony Controller you can use $this->get('wk_google_spreadsheet'); It is a shorthand for $this->container->get('wk_google_spreadsheet');